# Select a random Guild member using Discord.js

Tags: javascript, random, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that based off of one of the april fools videos will mention a random member of teh server. unfortuneately ive had no luck with everything ive googled.

I would like to mention I'm still very new to javascript and discord.js

the best ive found so far is:

```js
interaction.guild.members.random();
```

and that didnt work (it told me its not  function)

Comment: It should be `interaction.guild.members.cache.random()`

Comment: Thank you that was what I was missing. Also if anyone finds this make sure you specify what you want after the .random() for me it was id

Comment: Please do not put "solved" in the title. The system doesn't consider the question answered, and will not show it to others looking for solutions to the same problem. Instead, post the answer and accept it.

Comment: How do i do that? (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

> It should be interaction.guild.members.cache.random() –
> Zsolt Meszaros

turns out I was missing the cache part of the command.